# The recaptcha on data stackexchange isn't working

Tags: bug, data-explorer, captcha

[image]

Is this a temporary situation or something that needed to be reported?

Comment: Its a known issue that ought to be fixed sooner rather than later.

Comment: Fix it in 6-8 weeks?

Comment: @StephenRauch I would normally agree 100% with that estimate but no matter how I bend the space-time continuum there is not enough left till the end of this month ...

Comment: @rene: Unless we have [1.21 gigawatts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future#Plot) (and a [flux capacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeLorean_time_machine#Operation)).